# Laravel jQuery AJAX Live Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been trying to make a live search input for a webpage to search for data in my database. So far I have come up with this:

***Controller:***

```
public function launchsitefilter($site_code, Request $request) {
    $launchsites = DB::table('launchsites')->where('site_code', $site_code)->get();
    if(! $launchsites){
        return abort(404);
    }
    $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->get();
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $output="";
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                                    ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
        if ($launchsitesatellite)
        {
            foreach ($launchsitesatellite as $key => $launchsitesatellites) {
            $output ='<tr>'.
                    '<td>'. $launchsitesatellites->satname .'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->norad_cat_id.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_type.'</td>'.
                    '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    return view('pages/launchsite-filter', compact('launchsites', 'launchsitesatellite'));        
}
```

***Script:***

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
$value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url  : '{{$launchsitename->site_code}}',
        data : {'search':$value},
        success:function(data) {
            console.log(data);      
        }
    });
});
```

***Blade:***

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search"></input>
```

When I type something into the input I get this error in the console:

> GET http://space-observe.dev/launch-site/JSC?search=search term 500 (Internal Server Error)

I am guessing the Javascript is working while there is an error in my controller. What would you have to do to get the live search to work and display the results.

Comment: add `dd($launchsites);` before the return statement. And tell the result

Comment: Can you watch error log?

Comment: @SimonSchnell I get an array with the data I need from the database. Same goes for the `$launchsitesatellite`.

Comment: @ArthurQocharyan From the `laravel.log` I get `ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::$satname`. I am guessing something is undefined in my controller.

Comment: add this `error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }  ` to the ajax method and tell the result.

Comment: @SimonSchell I get a `500 (Internal Server Error)` and `Status: error`error - even when I type something into the input.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be a `->get()` at the end of the `DB::table` part?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I already get the database with `$launchsitesatellite`. I think I don't need to get it again with `if ($request->ajax())`

Comment: @D.777KLM I think you should because you're building a query but never retrieving the results.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Would agree with you - I guess I am doing a simple mistake. The Javascript works, so I guess the problem would lay in my controller. I think the most simple thing to do would be to pull `$launchsitesatellite` once and then somehow add AJAX to it.

Comment: @D.777KLM You should split the logic in the `index` method into two parts: the first handles a normal request and the second handles an ajax request. Make sure that both parts return a form of response!

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I managed to finish it, but it turned out very buggy and not that good. Would you have any examples for me to see?

Comment: What is the route for this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd rewrite your code like the following, it should work:

```
public function launchsitefilter($site_code, Request $request) {

    $launchsites = DB::table('launchsites')->where('site_code', $site_code)->get();
    if(! $launchsites){
        return abort(404);
    }

    if ($request->ajax()) 
    {
        $output="";
        // This is the ->get() I'm referring to in the comments.
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
                                                    ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')->get();
        if ($launchsitesatellite)
        {
            foreach ($launchsitesatellite as $key => $launchsitesatellites) {
            $output .='<tr>'.
                    '<td>'. $launchsitesatellites->satname .'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->norad_cat_id.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'.$launchsitesatellites->object_type.'</td>'.
                    '</tr>';
            }
        }

        return $output;
    }
    else {
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->get();

        return view('pages/launchsite-filter', compact('launchsites', 'launchsitesatellite'));        
    }

}
```

Note that the function is split into two parts, right after the check if the site containts launch sites.

Both parts return their own response, the ajax part returns an HTML response and the normal part returns a view.

Also note the `->get()` I added which should fix the problem your code had.

At last, you forgot a dot (`.`) when you wanted to add al the rows to `$output`, which would only show you the last result.

Comment: Works perfectly! One thing - Before I returned the database I would have filtered it by the `site-code`, so the page would only display the rows with that specific code. I used this to achieve it: `$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->get();`. Is there anyway I can only search the filtered database and not my whole database?

Comment: and also one thing - Is there a way to filter the database - for example I have a column (object_type) that defines the type of the object (Payload or Body). Is there anyway to make a checkbox to filter it? Thanks!

Comment: In regards to filtering with `->where('site', $site_code)`, it did not work. It stills searches the whole database.

Comment: @D.777KLM Those are like 3 different questions, but I'll point you in the right direction: For the filtering: `DB` returns an instance of [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections) which offers quite some filtering options, check out the `where` method, which is pretty much the same as for the `DB` class. So if you want to filter the results from the DB, just chain another where method: `$filtered = $results->where('thing', 'some_value')`; and for the checkbox: just check if the value of object_type is equal to payload and if so, add `checked` to the checkbox html.

Comment: I tried creating a filter using this code, but unfortunately it did not work. I have asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45515113/laravel-jquery-ajax-live-filter